# How to replace backslash followed by 2 letters with empty string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, str-replace, regexp-replace

Following is the test string and we need to replace the '\xa' with ''

> 'FF 6 VRV AVENUE SUBRAMANIYAM PALAYAM PinCode:-\xa0641034'

i was using the following set of lines in python to do the objective but to no use

```
new_str = str.replace(r'\\xa', '')
```

but the output is same

> 'FF 6 VRV AVENUE SUBRAMANIYAM PALAYAM PinCode:-\xa0641034'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to replace the unicode character '\xa0' -

```
s = 'FF 6 VRV AVENUE SUBRAMANIYAM PALAYAM PinCode:-\xa0641034' 
s = s.replace('\xa0', '') 
print(s)
#'FF 6 VRV AVENUE SUBRAMANIYAM PALAYAM PinCode:-641034'
```